# Administrator cannot delete file

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

So I created a jar file in IntelliJ and tried to move it, but it said I needed administrative permission to do it. So, as administrator, I clicked ok, but it didn't work. I then attempted to delete the file, but it wouldn't let me. So I pulled up command prompt (ran it as administrator) and entered del "". It said access is denied. I then right clicked on it, opened properties, clicked security, clicked advanced, and under owner, it said "unable to display current owner" and next to it, it said change. I clicked change, and it told me "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings" What should I do to delete it?

This is a permission error for a single file, not a folder. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: That "duplicate" problem *specifically* states that Lockhunter doesn't work and is a completely different scenario. Please read more than just the title before marking a question duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a program called lockhunter to fix it.